# Magento Catalog search returns blank page

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

I am having a strange issue.

I am working on developing a theme based on out of the box Luma theme for a Magento 2 site.

For the default page in theme, I am overriding it to use 3-column layout.

I am not overriding or rewriting anything in *Magento_CatalogSearch*. 
**So, the Problem :** Whenever I try to search any term on the site, it returns nothing but the blank page.

Upon checking the html, it generates up to blank side-bar div then closes the page abruptly, Note: it is not terminating the page, but ends it with the closing of tags.

I checked the Magento logs, as well as the Apache and the PHP logs, but I could not find any error message related in there.

Please, let me know if you have faced a similar issue or if I am missing any place to debug / dig into to solve the issue / dig out more information .

Thanks in Advance,